# Change Item of Flatlist on click of button which is outside of it in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have an array of images which I am able to display using `FlatList`, also when clicked on an image it also displayed in bigger size which is outside `FlatList`. I have a left and right icon beside the bigger image, which should be used to show the next or previous image from the current image shown.

Below is my code:

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(img1);
const [imageSet, setImageSet] = useState([img1,img2,img3,img4]);
return (
<SafeAreaView>
    <View
          style={{height: 400,width: 100}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                //What should I do here
            }}>
            <Icon name={'chevron-left'} color={Colors.primary} size={54} />     // left press icon
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Image style={{height: 350, width: 300}} source={selectedImage} />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                //What should I do here
            }}>
            <Icon name={'chevron-right'} color={Colors.primary} size={54} />     // right press icon    
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    <FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={imageSet}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
              setSelectedImage(item);
              }}>
                <Image
                source={item}
                key={index}
                style={{
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  resizeMode: 'contain',
                }}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )}
    />
</SafeAreaView>
);
```

I am unable to figure out how to show next or previous image . Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `selectedImage` taking the next image in `imageSet`. The only problem is identify what image you selected in `imageSet` array. For this you could use another state variable. Something like:

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(img1);
const [imageSet, setImageSet] = useState([img1,img2,img3,img4]);
const [indexImageSel, setIndexImageSel] = useState(0); //<-- 0 because the default value for selectedImage is img1
```

Then on `FlatList` `TouchableOpacity` you store image index selected:

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
              setSelectedImage(item);
              setIndexImageSel(index); // <-- store image index selected
              }}>
                <Image
                source={item}
                key={index}
                style={{
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  resizeMode: 'contain',
                }}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

And then the logic for left and right arrow:

```
<View
          style={{height: 400,width: 100}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                //What should I do here? decrement index and set selectedImage
                let newIndex = (indexImageSel - 1) % imageSet.length;
                setSelectedImage(imageSet[newIndex]);
                setIndexImageSel(newIndex);
            }}>
            <Icon name={'chevron-left'} color={Colors.primary} size={54} />     // left press icon
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Image style={{height: 350, width: 300}} source={selectedImage} />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                //What should I do here? increment index and set selectedImage
                let newIndex = (indexImageSel + 1) % imageSet.length;
                setSelectedImage(imageSet[newIndex]);
                setIndexImageSel(newIndex);
            }}>
            <Icon name={'chevron-right'} color={Colors.primary} size={54} />     // right press icon    
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```